# Build your own Street View with Google Street View API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there is a way to upload my own panoramic images of our house/building using Google Street View API, then use Google Street View Engine to navigate through them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to make custom street view panoramas: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#CustomStreetView

Here's a great sample of someone who has done this: http://www.gta4.net/map/

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing a similar project for a large building.

First, you need some way to generate a 360 degree panorama for the images.  I've adapted [hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) to be used in a set of bash scripts to generate the panos automatically in a Linux box.  So, I just upload the images to a folder, execute the script with the folder location and number of images per panorama and leave it alone.  Depending on the number of images you have per panorama, expect to wait 5-45 minutes for each panorama.

Second, check out the [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#CustomStreetView) link for how to use JS and StreetView.  I think your task will be easier as you can probably write all your locations inside the JS file rather than relying on database calls and parsing.

Third, make sure your usage is under the limits set by the API if you're not paying for the service.  If you go over the daily limit, the tour won't be available.

Comment: Sorry to bring up a very old post. But did you ever release this script?

I am looking to create the same but need to automatically create panoramas on the fly for street view mapping.

Comment: @Konvict67, feel free to email me at jjohns98684 AT gmail.com for details.